# How to store the nested hash path of the xml response?

Tags: ruby, xml, hash, savon

I have the following xml response converted to hash from savon

```
{:read_measurements_list_response=>{:read_measurements_list_result=>{:sensor_data_list=>{:sensor_data=>[{:type=>"Humidity", :value=>"26.20"}, {:type=>"Temperature", :value=>"33.12"}, {:type=>"Light", :value=>"5501.0"}, {:type=>"SoilMoisture", :value=>"0.223"}, {:type=>"Conductivity", :value=>"0.031"}, {:type=>"GroundTemperature", :value=>"26.9"}]}}, :@xmlns=>"http://tempuri.org/"}}
```

so I can dig inside those sensor_data key-pairs with

```
res_body[:read_measurements_list_response][:read_measurements_list_result][:sensor_data_list][:sensor_data]
```

How can I store this path into a variable so I can change it whenever the xml response changes structure? I have tried using several things but none work. It would be nice to be able to do res_body[hash_path].

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two things:

> 1. How can I store this path into a variable?

It depends on your environment: You could store it in a database, a file, hardcode it in your code, pass it as a default value for a method, etc.

> 2. It would be nice to be able to do res_body[hash_path]

You'll have to roll your own solution. Something like this could work:

```
def hash_search(hash, keys)
  return hash.fetch(keys.first, nil) if hash.blank? || keys.size <= 1
  return hash_search(hash.fetch(keys[0], {}), keys[1..-1])
end

> hash = {a: {b: {c: 1}}}
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1}}}
> hash_search(hash, [:a, :b, :c])
=> 1
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with what I asked. I just want to know how to store the hash path that leads to the inner array of hashes so that 1) I can let the user edit this path variable accordingly whenever the default one needs tweaking 2) I can store it as a constant on the top of my ruby script so that someone can easily find it and modify it if needed.